# AJAX 404 error on Laravel 5.5 artisan server

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I am using Laravel 5.5, PHP 7, on Bitnami WAMP stack and am getting a 404 error when I send an AJAX request via GET to a route that hits a controller method.

Here is web.php:

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index'); //works
Route::get('/loadstores/{$city}', 'HomeController@show'); //404
Route::view('/aboutus', 'aboutus'); //works
```

HomeController.php:

```
public function show($city) //never gets here
{
    $stores = DB::table('stores')->where('city', $city);
    return response()->json([
        'success' => "ok"
    ]);

}
```

googlemaps.js:

```
function getIP(){
    $.getJSON('http://ip-api.com/json/', function(result) {
        console.log(result);
        userIPlocation = {lat: result.lat, lng: result.lon};
        userCity = result.city;
        getStoresByCity();
    });
}


function getStoresByCity(){
    userCity = "new york"; //test
    $.ajax({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        },
        method:'GET',
        url:'/loadstores',
        data:{city:userCity},
        dataType: 'JSON',
        done:function(data){
            console.log("hi"); //never gets here
            console.log(data);
        },
        fail:function(xhr,status,error){
            console.log("fail"); //never gets here
            console.log(xhr,status,error);
        }
    });
}
```

This is the message in Chrome console: http://localhost:8000/loadstores?city=new%20york 404 (Not Found) GET

I have the csrf token set but I don't believe it is even needed because this is a GET request.

Of note I am using PHP artisan serve, so Apache doesn't play into this because this is my .htcaccess and I never get redirected to google

.htcacesss:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Redirect 301 / https://google.com
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

This is php artisan route:list:

```
    +--------+----------+--------------------+------+-------------------------------------------+--------------+
    | Domain | Method   | URI                | Name | Action                                    | Middleware   |
    +--------+----------+--------------------+------+-------------------------------------------+--------------+
    |        | GET|HEAD | /                  |      | App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@index | web          |
    |        | GET|HEAD | api/user           |      | Closure                                   | api,auth:api |
    |        | GET|HEAD | loadStores/{$city} |      | App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@show  | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD | aboutus            |      | \Illuminate\Routing\ViewController        | web          |
```

I have cleared the route cache many times. If I remove the parameter sent to /loadstores as well as the $city in show(), I get the JSON success message on the page.

Very confused here, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your route `Route::get('/loadstores/{city}', 'HomeController@show');` means that it binds the route to an url following a pattern of `/loadstores/new-york` and binds `new-york` to the variable `$city` in your controller.

The first thing to notice is that the `$` in your route definition is not needed there and should be removed, changing the route to: `Route::get('/loadstores/{city}', 'HomeController@show')`.

The second thing is that you now try to bind a GET parameter whereas your route expects a query parameter. If you change the url to `loadstores/new-york` it should work. Or if you want to use the GET parameter change it to `Route::get('/loadstores`, "HomeController@show");`

Comment: This is the most helpful response. It helped me understand the problem's root cause and showed me the solution. The other answers were good but this response was the most accurate.

Answer (score 0):

do the following changes :

in your **routes/web.php** :

```
Route::get('/loadstores/{city}', 'HomeController@show');
```

in your **HomeController** :

```
public function show(Request $request,$city) 
{
    $stores = DB::table('stores')->where('city', $city)->get();
    return response()->json([
        'success' => "ok",
        'stores'=>$stores
    ]);
}
```

in **googlemaps.js** :

```
function getIP(){
    $.getJSON('http://ip-api.com/json/', function(result) {
        console.log(result);
        userIPlocation = {lat: result.lat, lng: result.lon};
        userCity = result.city;
        getStoresByCity(userCity);
    });
}


function getStoresByCity(userCity){

    $.ajax({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        },
        method:'GET',
        url:`/loadstores/${userCity}`,
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success:function(data){
            console.log(data);
        },
        error:function(xhr,status,error){
            console.log(xhr,status,error);
        }
    });
}
```